# It is possible to change the color of periphery of Pie Chart in Chart.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, charts

Hi I'm making a pie chart using Chart.js. I have a small issue about styling. The background of pie chart is purple and I want to make the  periphery of pie chart purple. Default color is white.

Is it possible to change the color of  periphery from default color?

Current view

This is the current view. Periphery is white. I want to change it to purple to assimilate it to the background.

[image]

Code

```
export default class Categories extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        slideOpen : false,
        piData : piData
      }

this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.update = this.update.bind(this);
}

handleClick(){
    this.setState({
        slideOpen : !this.state.slideOpen
    })
    console.log(!this.state.slideOpen)
}

update() {
  var piData;
  this.setState({
    piData : piData
  })
console.log('data' + piData)
}    

render(){
 console.log('check' + piData)
 const CategoriesPanel = this.state.slideOpen? "slideOpen" : "";
 const { length } = this.props
 console.log( 'result' + piData )

  var totalData = piData + piData2 + piData3 + piData4 + piData5;

  let newpiData =  function() {
   return parseInt((piData /  totalData ) * 100 ) };

   let newpiData2 =  function() {
   return parseInt((piData2 /  totalData ) * 100) };

   let newpiData3 =  function() {
   return  parseInt((piData3 /  totalData ) * 100) };

   let newpiData4 =  function() {
   return  parseInt((piData4 /  totalData ) * 100) };

   let newpiData5 =  function() {
   return  parseInt((piData5 /  totalData ) * 100) };

   console.log('update data ' + newpiData())

  console.log('question item piData parent component' + piData)


  const data = {
  labels: [
    'question1',
    'question2',
    'question3',
    'question4',
    'question5'
   ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [ newpiData() , newpiData2(), newpiData3(), newpiData4(), newpiData5()],
    backgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ]
  }]};
return(
 <div>
 <div id="chart" className={CategoriesPanel}>
 <Pie style={{"fontSize" : "20px" }}data={data}/>
 <div className="categoriesSlide" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.slideOpen? <img src={Arrowup} alt="arrowup" className="arrowup" /> : <img src={Arrowdown} alt="arrowdown" className="arrowdown"/>}</div>
<button onClick={this.update} className="chartButton">Update Information</button></div>

 <div className="clear">

 <List  />
 <ListSecond />
 <ListThird />
 <ListFourth />
 <ListFifth />
 </div>
 </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as that: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#dataset-properties

```
const data = {
  labels: [
    'question1',
    'question2',
    'question3',
    'question4',
    'question5'
   ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [ newpiData() , newpiData2(), newpiData3(), newpiData4(), newpiData5()],
    backgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ],
    borderColor: ["purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple"]
  }]};
```

As you can see I have added `borderColor` property for data set which is in fact array just like `backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can change border color.Use `bordercolor` property for this.  You need  to use array of borderColor . Here borderColor  array length is equal to  No. of pie chart slices

```
borderColor:['purple','purple','purple','purple','purple']


 datasets: [{
    data: [ newpiData() , newpiData2(), newpiData3(), newpiData4(), newpiData5()],
    backgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ],
  borderColor:['purple','purple','purple','purple','purple']
  }]};
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NadBvz

DOCS:  http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#dataset-properties